# Spring boot - Analize with SonarLint block code

Tags: spring-boot, sonarlint

The SonarLint tells me that I can reduce this block of code:

```
if (item != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(item.getDateService())) {
    LocalDate dateConverted = MapperUtil.convertToLocalDate(item.getDateService());
    if (dateConverted != null) {
        if (item.getInstallId() == null) {
            if (dateConverted.getYear() == year) {
                letter = "A";
            } else {
                if (dateConverted.getYear() == year - 1) {
                    letter = "C";
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (dateConverted.getYear() == year) {
                letter = "E";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 21 to the 15 allowed. How to refactor and reduce the complexity
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting out some of the logic to another method - innerCall:

```
    if (item != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(item.getDateService())) {
        LocalDate dateConverted = MapperUtil.convertToLocalDate(item.getDateService());
        if (dateConverted != null) {
            letter = innerCall(item, dateConverted); 
        }
    }
```

...

```
public String innerCall(ItemClass item, DateConvertedClass dateConverted) {
    String letter = null;
    if (item.getInstallId() == null) {
        if (dateConverted.getYear() == year) {
            letter = "A";
        } else {
            if (dateConverted.getYear() == year - 1) {
                letter = "C";
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (dateConverted.getYear() == year) {
            letter = "E";
        }
    }
    return letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the SonarLint's rule is not about reducing a block of code, but reducing its complexity. That's because there are too much nested if-blocks (same problem with too much loops and so on).

You need to split the code in order to respect this rule.

**Watch out :** in some cases, `letter` don't get any value in your original code, so your refactoring must consider this. If the variable is null before your code, the example given in [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75257061/11819862) is correct. Else (for example it has the value "B", you need to test the value returned by the inner method, like:

```
final String innerCallResult = innerCall(item, dateConverted);
if (innerCallResult != null) {
    letter = innerCallResult;
}
```

To sum up this warning part, it depends on your needs.